# iterate through data from span tags

Tags: jquery, for-loop, iteration, html

I'm trying to select the data from a few span tags I have, the first tag logs in the console, but after that the value is "undefined"

The erb that generates the span tag:

```
<%= image.connections.each do |conn| %>
    <span class="connection" data-pos-x="<%= conn.pos_x %>"></span>
    <span class="connection" data-pos-y="<%= conn.pos_y %>"></span>
<% end %>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
console.log($("span").attr('data-pos-x'));
console.log($("span").attr('data-pos-y'));
```

There are multiple x-y coordinates generated from the erb, so I need a way to iterate through all the coordinates but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("span.connection").each(function() {
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');
    if (xpos !== undefined) {
        console.log("X: "+xpos);
    }
    if (ypos !== undefined) {
        console.log("Y: "+ypos);
    }
});
```

Comment: You sir are a saint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Encase your code in `DOM Ready event handler` And then iterate over then using `$.each`

```
$(function() {

   $('span.connection').each(function() {
      // cache the current span
      var $this = $(this),
          xCord = $this.data('pos-x') !== undefined ? $this.data('pos-x') : '--',
          yCord = $this.data('pos-y') !== undefined ? $this.data('pos-y') : '--',

      console.log('X-cord : ' + xCord + ' :: ' + 'Y-cord : ' + yCord)

   });
```

});

-

`$("span").attr('data-pos-x')` also works.. But it is a better practice to use 
data method to retrieve custom attributes.

Comment: Notice that each span has either an X coord or a Y coord, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the elements to iterate you can

```
$(".connection").each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data();
    console.log(data);
});
```

if you need the data in an array

```
var dataPoints = $.map($(".connection"), function(index, element){
    var data = $(element).data();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
});
```